# Garbage in string parameters of events

Tags: events, string

I have an event defined like this:

```
event Created(
    address indexed target,
    string indexed name
);
```

I do

```
emit Created(..., _name); // called function with _name = "comment"
```

which gives

```
0xd69ce70c72e2e7191b71ef82881773fbf30510f24a3450f02d555b5f04ac9702
```

or

```
0x2361458367e696363fbcc70777d07ebbd2394e89fd0adcaf147faccd1d294d60
```

in the Ganache event explorer:

[image]

How can I convert this back to `comment`? `web3.toAscii()` just returns garbage.

Comment: Call `const x = web3.fromAscii("comment");`. What you get in `x`, is what you should see in Ganache explorer. My guess is that you're looking at the wrong thing, since `x` should end with something like 50 zeros (while the first 14 characters are gonna be your "comment").

Comment: I figured as much but I don't see where I could do anything wrong. If the type / storage requirement were wrong, solidity would complain with warnings and compile errors. The contract is deployed, the decoded signature in Ganache is "Created(target: address, name: string)" and the value is as above.

Comment: @goodvibration Added screenshot

Comment: Change that `string` to `bytes32`, then run again and tell us what you see.

Comment: Indexed values of dynamic type like string are not stored directly with the event instead they are replaced by `keccak256(value)`.

Comment: @Ismael Why does the hash change with every event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because all array types (which includes `string` and `bytes`) are hashed. [See the documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.13/contracts.html#events):

> If you use arrays (including string and bytes) as indexed arguments, its Keccak-256 hash is stored as a topic instead, this is because a topic can only hold a single word (32 bytes).

If you need the original value, you will have to remove the option `indexed` from the event parameter and filter the events yourself.